# Apache 2.2 Cent Os Subdomain Virtual Host not working

Tags: apache, centos, apache2.2

I am trying to add domain and subdomain in apache virtual host. I already created the subdomain and pointed to my type A record. I dont see any issues over there.

Below is my httpd.conf entry: now only my root domain i am able to access, subdomain I could not access, I have gone through many links, but nothing worked for me.

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName admin.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/admin"
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone help me on this please ?

Comment: How are you trying to access this? From localhost? From another PC on your local network? Or is it remote over the web?

Comment: did you do `a2ensite` ?

Comment: From AWS EC2 instance, I also created routing property...

Comment: a2ensite? I am not getting you, sorry

Comment: `sudo a2ensite admin.mydomain.com`